# selecting site-template

Tags: site-template

Hello I am beginner in SP.

I want to create a basic portal for our company's HR department. We have a taxonomy, so we want to have a tree view menu on the left , and a section in the center where we display some static content.

When creating a site , Which template is the most suitable?

Answer (score 0):

There is no site template containing any *"tree view on the left"* based on Taxonomy.

It sounds like you're trying to create a site for your HR department, so the **Team Site** template is most suitable. You can enable **metadata navigation** for any list or library and link that to your taxonomy, see an explanation here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-HA101820113.aspx

If you were using SharePoint 2013 you would have a different kind of navigation based on Taxonomy.